# where do i put my my javascript program after i have written it on notepad

Tags: javascript

I have written a program in javascript form on notepad, but I don't know how to take that information and make a program, I have multiple browsers so I don't care which one I use if I can just figure out how to use it.

Comment: save it as a `.js` file, and include it in `html` files you wish to see the code in action

Comment: Your first javascript file [howto](http://www.math.grin.edu/~rebelsky/Tutorials/JavaScript/EdMedia97/Exercises/firstjs.html)

Comment: Have a look at http://www.w3.org/wiki/Your_first_look_at_JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either put it directly in your HTML file like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Your JavaScript code here
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Your HTML here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Or you can save your javaScript code as a .js file and link it to your HTML page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="javascriptfile.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Your HTML here -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Once you have done either of those methods, save your HTML file and preview it in a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

You create a `.html` and `.js` file and load the javascript in:

```
<html>
   <head> 
      <title>My first page</title>
   </head>
   <body> 
     <!-- page HTML here-->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="your_file.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Or, you can put the script in the `.html` file:

```
<html>
   <head> 
      <title>My first page</title>
   </head>
   <body> 
     <!-- page HTML here-->
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var name = "User";
        document.title = document.title.replace("My", name+"'s");
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Note that I put javascript files **at the end of the document**. This makes pages load faster - executing script **stops** (almost) **all activity**. But normally, the javascript is located at `<head>`.
Usual approach:

```
<html>
   <head> 
      <title>My first page</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="your_file.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body> 
     <!-- page HTML here-->
   </body>
</html>
```

Its also good to know, that the scripts will be executed where whey are. This is important with `document.write`, `alert` and `document.getElementById` (as a beginner, you may not know this function, but you'll learn to use it later). Have an example:
This code works:

```
<div id="div_id">Hello world!</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var div_element = document.getElementById("div_id");
    alert(div_element.innerHTML);
</script>
<i>I will appear after you confirm alert()</i>
```

This one returns error, because the `<div>` is after `<script>` and does not exist upon execution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var div_element = document.getElementById("div_id");
    alert(div_element.innerHTML);   //ERROR: div_element is null!
</script>
<div id="div_id">Hello world!</div>
<i>I will appear after you confirm alert()</i>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just run it as

`node file.js`

after installing Node.

Comment: What does Node.js have to do with anything he was asking? He was simply asking, as a beginner, how to execute Javascript....he is a loooong way from Node.

Comment: @patricksweeney Node REPL is the simplest way I know to just run pure javascript that's been "written on notepad."  `sudo apt-get install node; node < input.txt`, done.  Or if it's on a physical notepad, well, REPL was designed for that type of situation.

Comment: @patricksweeney I'm aware of the cheekiness but it's a 100% correct answer and arguably the simplest.  There's not terribly much else you can do with a question like this while answering it constructively.